# Does physical contact (by a person) with a cast Patronus shield negatively influence the effectiveness of the Expecto Patronum spell?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, dementors

When a *Patronus* confronts a *Dementor*, the protective *Patronus* spell appears to be a solid shield. Thinking about a combined Dark Wizard/Dementor attack against Harry made me wonder if physical contact from a wizard would affect the effect of a *Patronus* spell, so I'm asking if JKR establishes whether or not the spell could be influenced by contact with people.

> Does physical contact by a person with a cast Patronus shield negatively influence the effectiveness of the Expecto Patronum spell?

Comment: Well, I'm sure they're tangible at times. I suppose one could... err, push a Patronus off a cliff. Not very exciting though.

Comment: Don't think there's any canon info (at least, outside PotterLess).

Comment: But why would you plausibly suspect that a contact with a human would have any difference to a corporeal Patronus?

Comment: @DVK Thought a dark wizard/dementor tag team attack could come in handy. Wizard takes the shield down, Harry gets his soul sucked. Strategy was never one of JKRs strong points. Wondered if JKR addressed it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only a couple of ways to stop a Patronus that we see:

- If the caster becomes worried or unhappy.
- Finite Incantatem (Most probably)

It appears that a corporeal Patronus is intangible, in which case physical contact is impossible, but there is the possibility *could* be tangible at times. If they are tangible, then one surely could kick it, but I'm sure that the protective enchantment wouldn't cease to work merely by physical contact.

The movie shows dementors colliding into a Patronus shield, and it doesn't cease to work. Though this might not be canon, considering it's the movie.